# Android app using mobile data while connected to a wifi with no internet access

Tags: android, react-native, connection, wifi, iot

I need to update a Google Map instance inside my app while I’m connected to an ioT device via Wi-Fi but without internet access.
I found that if I connect to the device directly from inside my app, the phone will connect to the device access point and simultaneously show 4G connection badge active.
So, I can navigate on internet through browser or other Apps but from inside my App I don’t have internet access… I don’t see the “missing connection” banner showing when I try to make internet requests but all the requests pass through the wifi with no internet access and so the Google Map instance inside my app will not update and I can only see a blank grid even if I see the 4G badge active in the status bar…
Anyone have any solution?
I’m working with React Native and the same app in iOS does not have this problem

I tried to connect to the device wifi access point directly from inside my app and in this case the phone show the 4G banner active in the status bar even if I’m connected to the device via wifi without internet access, but the problem is that from inside my app all the requests pass through the wifi that have no internet access, and Android doesn’t not pass them to the mobile data working connection…
Outside my app I can navigate on internet in this status, but I need to do it from inside my app to update my Google map instance

Answer (score 0):

Your application uses the same OS system call but with some delay. If you want to control the connection state and check how your application reacts to network changes you can use NetInfo https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo#usage and log changes. For example:

```js
// Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```